# Pass-by-reference mutable variable in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pass-by-reference

I have a basic question about multi-threading in Python: I have a list and I need modify this in a thread. I understand that an list is a mutable type: [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

But, when I using thread the list is not behaving like a mutable type:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def f(l, i, n):
    l.acquire()
    i.append(n)
    l.release()
    print "in:", i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    i = []
    for num in range(10):
        p = Process(target=f, args=(lock, i, num))
        p.start()
        p.join()

    print "out:", i
```

output

```
in: [0]
in: [1]
in: [2]
in: [3]
in: [4]
in: [5]
in: [6]
in: [7]
in: [8]
in: [9]
out: []
```

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is not using threads, but processes which does not share memory.

Use threads:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock  # <----

def f(l, i, n):
    l.acquire()
    i.append(n)
    l.release()
    print "in:", i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    i = []
    for num in range(10):
        p = Thread(target=f, args=(lock, i, num))  # <----
        p.start()
        p.join()

    print "out:", i
```

Comment: I tested this, but it looks like Python threads all executing on a single core! Can you tell me why?

Comment: Is possible to use Python Multiprocess and the list behave like a mutable type?

Comment: @AlanValejo, Reading [**Sharing state between processes - Python multiprocessing module documentation**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join on a seperate loop. By having the join in the same loop, it forces you to wait for the thread to complete before kicking off the next thread. See code below...

```html
from threading import Thread, Lock  # <----

def f(l, i, n):
    l.acquire()
    i.append(n)
    l.release()
    print "in:", i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    i = []
    for num in range(10):
        p = Thread(target=f, args=(lock, i, num))  # <----
        p.start()
        
    for num in range(10):
        p.join()   

    print "out:", i
```